# mysql query displaying incorrect rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query which currently should only display one row. However it somehow is displaying 4 rows as its result set even though 1) there are only three rows in the table to begin with 2) only one row matches the query criteria.

I am hoping someone might know what I am doing wrong with this MySql query

My database table structure is as below

```
smsid (int, auto increment), sms_type (text), sms_status (enum 'pending',sent'), 
sms_error (test), sms_message(text), sms_mp3file (varchar 50),
sms_sendon (datetime), send_sms_toid (int 5)
```

My table entries are as so (following the order of the table columns above)

```
31 | mp3 | pending |  | | helloworld.mp3 | 2013-11-20 16:16:00 | 7

30 | text  | sent |  | hello test |  | 2013-11-18 13:12:00 | 8 

29 | voice  | sent |  | testing 123 |  | 2013-11-18 10:05:00 | 18
```

My query is as below

```
SELECT sms_messages.*, sms_recipients.cust_profid, sms_recipients.sms_cellnumber, 
customer_smsnumbers.sms_number, customer_smsnumbers.sms_number 
FROM sms_messages, sms_recipients, customer_smsnumbers
WHERE sms_messages.sms_type='mp3' AND  sms_messages.sms_sendon <= '2013-11-21' 
AND sms_messages.sms_status='pending' AND 
sms_messages.send_sms_toid = sms_recipients.smsuser_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you have missed a `JOINING` clause for `customer_smsnumbers` table. Similar to `sms_messages.send_sms_toid = sms_recipients.smsuser_id` you need to have a join clause which either `connects sms_messages` with `customer_smsnumbers` table or connects `sms_recipients` with the `customer_smsnumbers` table.

In the absence of a join clause other (unintended) records are included in the result.

Comment: +1, but what I really love when they blame MySQL for not displaying the rows